# python os.path.isfile() returns True for some integers

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, path

Surely I am missing something obvious. How can `os.path.isfile()` return `True` when given a scalar value?

```
>>> for i in range(0,20):    print(os.path.isfile(i))
... 
False
False
False
False
False
False
False
False
False
False
False
False
False
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
```

I am executing this from an empty directory. Python 3.6. I've looked at other questions about `os.path.isfile()` but I did not find an answer to this.

Comment: How odd. I can't reproduce this. Do you get the same outcome regardless of your working directory?

Comment: I get a True for i=2 in my User directory - windows. ... `os.path.isfile(2)` -> `True` regardless of directory.

Comment: @khelwood the outcome differs. Not sure if depending on working directory or something else

Comment: What about trying the same with `os.stat`?

Comment: @khelwood It works for i=0,1 and 2 with this output:  os.stat_result(st_mode=8592, st_ino=3, st_dev=23, st_nlink=1, st_uid=1000, st_gid=5, st_size=0, st_atime=1595876800, st_mtime=1595876800, st_ctime=1595513032)

Comment: With i=3, I get: OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor: 3

Comment: What operating system?

Comment: @khelwood Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Well `os.path.isfile` calls `os.stat`, so it's that that's behaving weirdly. `os.stat` is platform dependent. I hope someone very knowledgeable notices this question because I'd be interested to find out the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's all in the docs:

- [os.path.isfile](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/os.path.html#os.path.isfile) returns `True` if *path* is an "existing" regular file.
- *path* "exists" if [os.path.exists](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/os.path.html#os.path.exists) returns `True`
- since version 3.3 *path* can be an integer - if it is an open *file descriptor* `os.path.exists` returns `True`
- [file descriptors](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/os.html#file-descriptor-operations) are small integers corresponding to a file that has been opened by the current process. For example, standard input is usually file descriptor 0, standard output is 1, and standard error is 2. Further files opened by a process will then be assigned 3, 4, 5, and so forth. (The name "file descriptor" is slightly deceptive; on Unix platforms, sockets and pipes are also referenced by file descriptors.)

Comment: Thanks. I am afraid I still don't understand where the values I got came from. So could you please explain, in layman's terms, why there is 13 times False and then 7 times False?

Comment: Each time the process opens a "file", it's assigned an integer "file descriptor". If that "file" is a regular file, `os.path.isfile` will return `True` on that integer.

Comment: Thanks! But the way I understand your explanation, it should assign lower values first. So how come first there is a bunch of False values?

Comment: Probably it opened other files in the past whose descriptors are now closed, but were not at the time the later ones were opened. Run `strace` or similar to find out, and/or see where these open descriptors are pointing; I'm guessing Python itself and your script file, and some system libraries used by Python.